# .htaacces rewrite (complex)

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want to rewrite all urls starting with example.com/svd/188 (after 188 will be ips and directories, like example.com/svd/188.1.1.1/maps/de_dust2.bsp) to site2.com/svd/188.1.1.1/maps/de_dust2.bsp (retain all after 188 and paste it into the new url...).

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /var/www/html/svd

RewriteRule ^188([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ http://site2.com/svd/188$1/$2/$3/$4 [R=301,L]

This doesn't really work. It only works for example.com/svd/188.1.1.1 (without any / and other directories and files like /maps/aa.text).
Please note that I want this redirect for anything starting with /svd/188 (and to copy the rest of the url to the second url...if you know what I mean).
Thanks for help.

Comment: if https, `RewriteRule (.*) https://site2.com/$1 [R=301,L]` does not do the thing?

Comment: I need to redirect all users trying to acces example.com/svd/188.1.1.1/maps/cfg (or other directories after the ip, which can differ) to othersite.com/svd/188.1.1.1/maps/cfg (or other directories the user has typed...) This is the thing... I don't nead http/https redirection, just this.

Comment: and that doesn't work...

Comment: May be you mean something like this - `^(https?:\/\/)?[^\/]+(?=\/svd\/188)`. Check it on https://regex101.com/r/gQcys4/6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question you write "for anything starting with /svd/188".

That means that the following should do what you ask:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?svd/188(.*)$ http://site2.com/svd/188$1 [R=301]
```

That rule should work likewise in the http servers host configuration or in  dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file). If you really have to use such a file, then it's interpretation needs to be enabled and that rule has to be place in such a file at top level, so inside the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).